# Resize Selection In Photoshop Like in GIMP

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, selections

About 15 years ago, I was a Photoshop user. Then I stopped using it and exclusively used GIMP. Now I'm trying to get back into Photoshop and there is one thing that is driving me absolutely nuts. I cannot figure out to modify a selection like you can in GIMP. Example below of what I mean by "modifying the selection."

In GIMP, when you make a selection. If you move your cursor over the edge, you get a box to resize the selection. Then you can click and drag to resize the selection on that edge/corner. You can also click and drag in the middle of the selection to move it. Is there any way to do this in Photoshop?

[image: GIMP Selection Resizing]
[Screen recording available on YouTube](https://youtu.be/NnLTPXsmxSM)

Comment: Menu bar > Select > Transform Selection will allow you to do resize the selection and move it.

Comment: Wow, that transform selection is pretty useful. Can't believe I've never used it before. (Insert "The More You know" gif here). I only wish it came up when you hovered over the selection.

Comment: @ispaany, thank you! I've searched all over for this. Aside from the inconvienance of extra steps, something else to note is once you're in the transform mode, the scroll wheel no longer works. 9 times out of ten when I'm using this functionality, I'm trying to get the selection pixel perfect, so I have zoom in rather far.